# Chunking large numbers in a group of three in php

Tags: php

I want to chunk large numbers. For example.

```
//between each three decimals a dot should be placed
33 thousand like this       33.000
33 milion   like this   33.000.000
```

How can I do this in php?

Comment: See [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format(
    $number, 
    0,         //amount of decimal points
    ',',       //decimal seperator
    '.'        //thousands seperator
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
number_format("33000",0,"",".");
number_format("33000000",0,"",".");
```